# groupby using combination of column index and column name

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I'm creating a function to filter many dataframes using  `groupby`. The dataframes look like below. However each dataframe does not always contain the same number of columns.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'xyz CODE': [1,2,3,3,4, 5,6,7,7,8],
    'a': [4, 5, 3, 1, 2, 20, 10, 40, 50, 30],
    'b': [20, 10, 40, 50, 30, 4, 5, 3, 1, 2],
    'c': [25, 20, 5, 15, 10, 25, 20, 5, 15, 10] })
```

For each dataframe I always apply groupby to the first column - which are named differently across dataframes. All other columns are named consistently across all dataframes.

My question: Is it possible to run groupby using a combination of column location and column names? How can I do it?

I wrote the following function and got an error `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`

```
    def filter_all_df(df):
        df['max_c'] = df.groupby(df.columns[0])['a'].transform('max')
        newdf = df[df['a'] == df['max_c']].drop(['max_c'], axis=1) 
        newdf['max_score'] = newdf.groupby([newdf.columns[0],'a','b'])['c'].transform('max')
        newdf = newdf[newdf['c'] == newdf['max_score']]
        newdf = newdf.sort_values([newdf.columns[0]]).drop_duplicates([newdf.columns[0], 'a','b', 'c'], keep='last')
        newdf.to_csv('newdf_all.csv')
        return newdf
```

Comment: Shouldn't the `.drop_duplicates` look like `.drop_duplicates([newdf.columns[0], 'a','b', 'c'], keep='last')`?

Comment: that's right, removed the extra pair of bracket in the edit

Comment: And you still get the error? (I don't.)

Comment: ohh! I just re-ran the code, error is gone! thanks for pointing out!